# How are React component instances different than other frameworks?

Tags: reactjs, components, instance

In the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html), React says that it doesn't really care for instances as the Components take props as input and outputs elements for you. It gives you an example at the top of how other frameworks have to create an instance and then connect it to the DOM to handle different events. But I don't understand how this is different than what React is doing.

You're not calling `new` on your component in React, but you still have to render it and create all the same handlers. And `this` inside the component still refers to the instance, so doesn't React still have to create an instance each time your component is rendered (even if it's a component inside an `<li>` that's being rendered several times at once).

Traditional frameworks will have to create multiple instances of the same component to connect to each DOM node it corresponds to, isn't that what React is doing too? How else can one component keep track of multiple `this`'s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, React creates **Component** *instance* **internally**. You don't need to worry about using `new`.

**React Element** is just a plain JavaScript Object that **describes** what you want to be rendered  (*React.Component* or *HTML Element*, if `type` is a String).

From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html#elements-describe-the-tree):

> **An element is not an actual instance.** Rather, it is a way to tell
>   React what you want to see on the screen. You can’t call any methods
>   on the element. It’s just an immutable description object with two
>   fields: type: (string | ReactClass) and props: Object1.

Comment: So essentially you're passing all of that responsibility to React - the creation and deletion of instances, that is

Comment: @stackjlei that's it!

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that *you the developer* are not having to write the code to do all that.  You just write the render method and your callbacks and let React worry about creating the DOM elements and the component instances and connecting them together.